# how to change en-uk datetime format to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss without am/pm

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

When I am passing datetime  value from a layer to another layer for `en-UK` culture , Datetime format get changed to `MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss`. It should be `dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss` .

I think reason may be am/pm in `en-uk` format. Below I have pasted my code.

```
var dtfrom = datepicker1.Text;
var dtto = datepicker2.Text;
DateTime dtfromval;

var language = hidCulture.Value.ToString();
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language);
try
{
    if (language=="en-UK")
    {
        dtfromval = DateTime.Parse(dtfrom, culture);
    }
```

Please tell me how to change `en-uk` datetime to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` ----i.e. 24 hr format.

Comment: try with DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: I have applied but still throwing excepation

Comment: can you share your exact code

Comment: Try `string date = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");`

Comment: can you try this
 var dtfrom = "20/02/2017 13:00:00";
 if (language == "en-UK")
            {
                string output = "";
                dtfromval = DateTime.ParseExact(dtfrom, "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture);
                output = dtfromval.ToString("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            }

Comment: There isn't an `en-uk` culture.

Comment: Do `datepicker1` and `2` not expose the selected `Date` as a `DateTime` value, rather than a string? If so, just use that. Stop messing around with *strings* and you'll stop having formatting *issues*.

Comment: en-GB is the UK / Great Britain culture, not en-UK.

Comment: what is the current date format ?